# IF formula from Excel to CASE (If) formula in Oracal Insight

Tags: oracle, excel-formula

In Excel my formula looks like =IF(AND(MONTH(NOW())=MONTH(A2), YEAR(NOW())=YEAR(A2)),"TRUE",...

Outcome is TRUE if month, year in cell A2 is current month, year...

In Oracle Insight a similar statement would appear as CASE WHEN ... and I am not sure how the rest would go...

I attempted to find an example that included the use of AND or how to call out month and year but I was unable to find the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current date with [sysdate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions191.htm#SQLRF06124) function in oracle.
Also, you can convert separate part of date, using [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions200.htm#i1009324) function, where you should indicate, [which part](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210) you want to get from date.

I hope, this exapmle will be useful for you: https://dbfiddle.uk/nelQK8Uf

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The answer you have given unfortunately does not answer the above question. I am looking for a formula similar to the one stated in my question. Although Oracle Insight can execute PL/SQL is seems to be missing some functions preventing a solution that is wholly PL/SQL based. The solution I am looking for would include the use of the CASE(if) expression.